# Remove click event on a parent but child is clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to click on a child but if I click on his parent the click isn't triggered. Here is what I tried.

```js
$("#parent").css("pointer-events","none");

$("#parent").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Clicked parent')
});

$("#child").click(function(e) {
    console.log('Clicked child');
});
```

```css
#parent{
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:red;
}

#child{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove the onclick handler on the parent but not to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#parent *:not(#child)")` can do this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#parent *:not(#child)").css("pointer-events","none");

  $("#parent *:not(#child)").on('click',function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log('Clicked parent')
  });

  $("#child").on('click',function(e) {
      console.log('Clicked child');
  });
});
```

```css
#parent{
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:red;
}

#child{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" style="">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I add `$("#parent").css("pointer-events","none");` the whole doesn't work 
unfortunately

Comment: you can use the same selector for `pointer-events` @executable

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.stopPropagation();` to the child `click` handler

```js
$("#parent").click(function(e) {

  console.log('Clicked parent');

});

$("#child").click(function(e) {
  console.log('Clicked child');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The red part is still clickable

Comment: @executable the question is not clear , you want it to be clickable or not.

Comment: I wanto to make the red part unclickable, that's why in my code I use `$("#parent").css("pointer-events","none");`

Comment: @executable then why you are attaching the click event to it?

Comment: To check if the event is still listening.

Comment: @executable if you dont attach click handler to it and add `e.stopPropagation();` to child it will never fire event on parent

Comment: Yes but I have an another handler on this element but I don't have hand on it, that's why I want to disable the click on this element